# Setup template for redirect URIs in google developer console

Tags: continuous-integration, google-oauth, developer-console

I try do auto-deploy for some project, when somebody *push* to git, deploying occurred for the branch and jenkins setup project and do deploy stuff on a server. For example:

```
|Branch  |URL (will be created)                  |  
|--------|---------------------------------------|  
|master  |http://master.my-project.example.com/  |  
|some    |http://some.my-project.example.com/    |  
|dev-2e  |http://dev-2e.my-project.example.com/  |
```

all is fine, but project need use google OAuth2, and there is a key, client id, client secret.

So I need setup not just one or just five redirect URIs for google authorization, I need *template*:
**http://*****.my-project.example.com/oauth2redirect**
When I try do this, I have error without any reason or explanation. When I just omit all URIs, no one URI is work, but I even agree with turning off this restriction.

Is there any ability to do this? Or programmatic API for adding new URI?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found any standard way to solve this problem.

> [How do I add "authorized redirect URIs" to Google OAuth2 using an API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31330824/how-do-i-add-authorized-redirect-uris-to-google-oauth2-using-an-api?rq=1)

Says: I need create own proxy server, that will be do redirects. And has the only allowed redirect URI in google console.